# Upload file via vbs and php

Tags: php, file-upload, vbscript

I'm trying to upload a .txt file to a server, vbs at client side and php at server side. Here is what I have done, the vbs part is messy as I copied it from somewhere, modified a bit cuz I do not know what to do. Sorry I'm new to vbs.

```
Dim sender

Dim strURL
Dim HTTP
Dim dataFile
Dim dataRequest
Dim objStream
strURL = "http://some-url/cgi-bin/upload.php"
Set HTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 2
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "test.txt"
dataFile = objStream.ReadText

sender = "testing"
dataRequest = "sender=" & sender & "&dat=" & dataFile

WScript.Echo "packet: " & dataRequest

HTTP.open "POST", strURL, False
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(dataRequest)

WScript.Echo "Now uploading file"

HTTP.send dataRequest
WScript.Echo HTTP.responseText

Set HTTP = Nothing
```

Here I am sending two things to the php file. One is $sender, a piece of string identifier for the uploader. Two, the txt file.

for example. Suppose a person sends the two data, "myperson" and hello.txt

the php should first create a directory from root, /uploads/myperson/

then upload the txt there. /uploads/myperson/hello.txt

The php is in /cgi-bin/upload.php

And here is the .php

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
echo "executed<br>";
$sender = $_POST['sender'];
echo "received sender=$sender";
$root = "../";
$target_dir = $root . "uploads/" . $sender . "/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["dat"]["name"]);
mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true) or die("cannot create directory");
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["dat"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) or die("cannot move file");
?>
```

The php can receive the $sender, but somehow cannot create a new directory based on $sender.

I tried removing the mkdir line, and upload the txt to current dir, however it replied "cannot move file", perhaps the file is never received?

I also noticed the vbs reads my txt file as unicode, although my txt file is in ANSI.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: or if not possible, is there another more efficient way for client side to upload files to server? I tried ftp before but I don't like giving away the ftp username and password.

Comment: You are not sending the name of the file, but he content in `&dat=" & dataFile` . And in the php part, use `file_put_contents` instead of `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: oh i see, but to upload a file, do I need to read the contents in vbs?

Comment: You will have to send the name of the file as a different field to the php file.    Yes, you need to send the content too.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll get it working soon